# MATLAB write string and then table to file

Tags: matlab

I need to write a string and a table to one text file.  The string contains a description of the data in the table, but is not the headers for the table. I am using R2019a which I guess means the "Append" writetable option does not work?  Please see my example data below:

```
% Load data
load cereal.mat;
table =  table(Calories, Carbo, Cups, Fat, Fiber, Mfg, Name, Potass);
string = {'This is a string about the cereal table'};
filename = "dummyoutput.sfc";

% How I tried to do this (which does not work!)
fid = fopen(filename, 'w', 'n');
fprintf(fid, '%s', cell2mat(string))
fclose(fid);
writetable(table, filename, 'FileType', 'text', 'WriteVariableNames', 0, 'Delimiter', 'tab', 'WriteMode', 'Append')
```

I get this error:

```
Error using writetable (line 155)
Wrong number of arguments.
```

Does anyone have a suggestion as to how to proceed?

Thanks!

Comment: `WriteMode` wasn't available in R2019a

Comment: Yes I understand this.  I am looking for a work around that is compatible with R2019a.

Comment: What is your operating system? It should be straight-forward to use shell commands to prepend a string to an existing file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit hacky, but here's an idea.

- Convert your existing table to a cell array with [table2cell](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table2cell.html).
- Prepend a row of cells which consists of your string, followed by empty cells.
- Convert the cell array back to a table with [cell2table](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2table.html), and write the new table to the file.

---

```
load cereal.mat;
table =  table(Calories, Carbo, Cups, Fat, Fiber, Mfg, Name, Potass);
s = {'This is a string about the cereal table'};
filename = "dummyoutput.sfc";

new_table = cell2table([[s repmat({''},1,size(table,2)-1)] ; table2cell(table)]);
writetable(new_table,filename,'FileType','text','WriteVariableNames',0,'Delimiter','tab');
```

---

```
>> !head dummyoutput.sfc
This is a string about the cereal table                          
70  5   0.33    1   10  N   100% Bran   280 
120 8   -1  5   2   Q   100% Natural Bran   135 
70  7   0.33    1   9   K   All-Bran    320 
50  8   0.5 0   14  K   All-Bran with Extra Fiber   330 
110 14  0.75    2   1   R   Almond Delight  -1 
110 10.5    0.75    2   1.5 G   Apple Cinnamon Cheerios 70 
110 11  1   0   1   K   Apple Jacks 30 
130 18  0.75    2   2   G   Basic 4 100 
90  15  0.67    1   4   R   Bran Chex   125
```